How to reposition X-label title
I am new to making LaTex and pgfplots, I am in the process of making a temperature scatter graph however I am encountering some problems I will outline in multiple posts otherwise the message will be too long:
Problem 1: X-axis label overlaps with x-axis ticks, when attempting to reposition it places alot of vertical space between axis and itself.

I desire it be be directly under the the x-axis.
This is my code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5] 
    \begin{axis}[
        title={Temperature Data from 1990 to 2022},
        xlabel={Year},
        ylabel={Temperature (°C)},
        grid=both,
        major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
        minor grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!10},
        xmin=1990, xmax=2031,
        ymin=22, ymax=31,
        xtick={1990,1991, 1992, 1993,1994,1995, 1996, 1997,1998,1999, 2000,2001, 2002,2003, 2004,2005 ,2006, 2007,2008, 2009,2010,2011, 2012,2013, 2014,2015, 2016, 2017,2018, 2019,2020, 2021,2022,2030},
        xticklabels={1990,1991, 1992,1993, 1994,1995, 1996, 1997,1998, 1999,2000, 2001,2002, 2003,2004, 2005,2006, 2007,2008, 2009,2010,2011,2012, 2013,2014, 2015,2016, 2017,2018, 2019,2020,2021, 2022,2030}, 
        xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=north east},
        ytick={20, 22,23, 24,25,26,27,28,29, 30,31},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        scatter,
        mark options={scale=1.5},
        width=15cm,
        height=10cm,
        xlabel style={at={(axis cs:2020,0)}, anchor=north}, 
    ]
   
    \addplot[only marks, blue] coordinates {
        (1990,25)(1991,24.6)(1992,24.1)(1993,24.2)(1994,28.2)(1995,25.1)(1996,24.9)(1997,25.3)(1998,26.3)(1999,25.2)(2000,27.2)(2001,22.5)(2002,27.1)(2003,25.5)(2004,26.1)(2005,27.1)(2006,27.7)(2007,27.6)(2008,24.4)(2009,27.3)(2010,25.9)(2011,26.9)(2012,27)(2013,27.1)(2014,25)(2015,30.3)(2016,26.6)(2017,26.1)(2018,28.6)(2019,29.1)(2020,25.5)(2021,26.2)(2022,26.5)(2030,28.10989)
    };
\addplot[domain=1990:2030,samples=33,no markers, dashed,black,thick] { (0.07503*(x) - 124.208) };
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

**Trouble shooting

***Found solution.
x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.13)},anchor=north},




Again here, you should move your solution part t a new (self.) answer, see my comment made here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730486/legend-marker-wont-change-persists-to-a-black-dot#comment1819105_730486

pgfplots offers a variety of anchor points, e.g. to the axis description cs: you used, to various labels etc. further down in ch. 4.9 Axis Description. Here I want to use an other option, which you can read from ch. 4.19 Alignment Options.
I illustrated a few of these in this answer To which entities can I anchor nodes in pgfplots?. Here I try referencing the xticklabel  and the axis.
As you can see, both from screenshot and comments in code, anchoring to the xticklabel  is a very confined place (no line drawn to the left). axis (AX) is what you want to anchor to. This centers arithmetically in a Tikz-ish way. If you feel, it should be visually more to the left, just add e.g. xshift=-13mm or so. (This visual impression may result from the missing gridlines, creating a visually separation {data left, something else whateverItIs right of it})
    \begin{axis}[
        name = AX,          % to refer to it later
...
    %     anchored to axis
    \node[  anchor=north,
            magenta,
            draw,
            yshift=-20mm] (B)  at (AX.south)    {AX};



\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % recommended
%\usepackage{amsmath}       % not needed here

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5] 
    \begin{axis}[
        name = AX,          % to refer to it later
        title={Temperature Data from 1990 to 2022},
%        xlabel={Year},     % <<< shall be in a separate node
        ylabel={Temperature (°C)},
        grid=both,
        major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
        minor grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!10},
        xmin=1990, xmax=2031,
        ymin=22, ymax=31,
        xtick={1990,1991, 1992, 1993,1994,1995, 1996, 1997,1998,1999, 2000,2001, 2002,2003, 2004,2005 ,2006, 2007,2008, 2009,2010,2011, 2012,2013, 2014,2015, 2016, 2017,2018, 2019,2020, 2021,2022,2030},
        xticklabels={1990,1991, 1992,1993, 1994,1995, 1996, 1997,1998, 1999,2000, 2001,2002, 2003,2004, 2005,2006, 2007,2008, 2009,2010,2011,2012, 2013,2014, 2015,2016, 2017,2018, 2019,2020,2021, 2022,2030}, 
        xticklabel style=   % <<<< extended
        {
            rotate=90,
            anchor=north east,
            name=XL,        % to refer to this object later
        },
        ytick={20, 22,23, 24,25,26,27,28,29, 30,31},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        scatter,
        mark options={scale=1.5},
        width=15cm,
        height=10cm,
%  >>>      xlabel style={at={(axis cs:2020,0)}, anchor=north}, 
    ]
   
    \addplot[only marks, blue] coordinates {
        (1990,25)(1991,24.6)(1992,24.1)(1993,24.2)(1994,28.2)(1995,25.1)(1996,24.9)(1997,25.3)(1998,26.3)(1999,25.2)(2000,27.2)(2001,22.5)(2002,27.1)(2003,25.5)(2004,26.1)(2005,27.1)(2006,27.7)(2007,27.6)(2008,24.4)(2009,27.3)(2010,25.9)(2011,26.9)(2012,27)(2013,27.1)(2014,25)(2015,30.3)(2016,26.6)(2017,26.1)(2018,28.6)(2019,29.1)(2020,25.5)(2021,26.2)(2022,26.5)(2030,28.10989)
    };
\addplot[domain=1990:2030,samples=33,no markers, dashed,black,thick] { (0.07503*(x) - 124.208) };
    \end{axis}

    % ~~~ label treatment ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    %     anchored to some x-label
    \node[  anchor=north,
            purple,
            draw,
            yshift=-10mm] (A)  at (XL.south)    {XL};
    \draw[dashed,teal] (XL.south) -- (A.north) -- (XL.south west);
    %  obvioulsy ... refers to itself, not to the "frame" ...
    
    %     anchored to axis
    \node[  anchor=north,
            magenta,
            draw,
            yshift=-20mm] (B)  at (AX.south)    {AX};
    \draw[dashed,brown] (AX.south west) -- (B.north) -- (AX.south)
                      -- (B.north) -- (AX.south east);
     
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

