Legend marker wont change, persists to a black dot
I am trying to change the legend marker to a black dashed line to match that of my linear regression but it persists as a black dot. I dont understand why this is occuring when I have defined the marker image.
This is what I have thus far:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
\begin{axis}[ 
legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north east},
    title={Temperature Data from 1990 to 2022},
    xlabel={Year},
    ylabel={Temperature (°C)},
    grid=both,
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    minor grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!10},
    xmin=1990, xmax=2031,
    ymin=22, ymax=31.5,
    xtick={1990,1991, 1992, 1993,1994,1995, 1996, 1997,1998,1999, 2000,2001, 2002,2003, 2004,2005 ,2006, 2007,2008, 2009,2010,2011, 2012,2013, 2014,2015, 2016, 2017,2018, 2019,2020, 2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027,2028,2029,2030},
    xticklabels={1990,1991, 1992,1993, 1994,1995, 1996, 1997,1998, 1999,2000, 2001,2002, 2003,2004, 2005,2006, 2007,2008, 2009,2010,2011,2012, 2013,2014, 2015,2016, 2017,2018, 2019,2020,2021, 2022,2030}, 
    xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=north east},
    ytick={20, 22,23, 24,25,26,27,28,29, 30,31},scatter,
    mark options={scale=1.5},
    width=15cm,
    height=10cm,
   x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.13)},anchor=north},
]


\addplot[only marks] coordinates {
    (1990,25)(1991,24.6)(1992,24.1)(1993,24.2)(1994,28.2)(1995,25.1)(1996,24.9)(1997,25.3)(1998,26.3)(1999,25.2)(2000,27.2)(2001,22.5)(2002,27.1)(2003,25.5)(2004,26.1)(2005,27.1)(2006,27.7)(2007,27.6)(2008,24.4)(2009,27.3)(2010,25.9)(2011,26.9)(2012,27)(2013,27.1)(2014,25)(2015,30.3)(2016,26.6)(2017,26.1)(2018,28.6)(2019,29.1)(2020,25.5)(2021,26.2)(2022,26.5)(2030,28.10989)
};
\addlegendimage{black,dashed};
\addlegendentry{$y=0.0750334x - 124.208, R^2 = 0.2039$}
\addplot[domain=1990:2030,no markers, dashed,black,thick] {(0.07503*(x) - 124.208)}; 




\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{landscape}


\end{document}



Nice +1 // Well now you have 1 focused question (very good), but confounded it with a solution, which should be an answer (Q==problem, A==answer, so we'll have 1 Q + many A, i.e. a solution manifold per problem).  May feel strange in the beginning, but is very useful once you start searching this place for solutions. // So I suggest: (A) moving your solution part to a separate answer (yes, you can answer to yourself), (B) accepting your answer, which is possible in a few days. // As a side effect, I would like to upvote your solution, but must mistakenly upvote your problem ... // Thank you

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please separate  answer and question. Anyway, this other question is similar.

Separated answer.

Found solution:
Using setting forget plot

for Example \addplot[only marks,forget plot,scatter] coordinates { ....data }; 
Therefore if you have a plot beforehand you must include forget plot setting to omit this plot from the legend if thats what you desire. Then in the plot you want featured on the legend then do not include forget plot And It will show with the correct legend image.
Complete code for reference
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\usepackage{cmbright}
%\usepackage{euler}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5] 
\begin{axis}[ 
xtick distance={90},
legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north east},
    title={December mean maximum temperature from 1990 to 2022},
    xlabel={Year},
    ylabel={Mean maximum temperature (°C)},
    grid=both,
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    minor grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=gray!10},
    xmin=1990, xmax=2030,
    ymin=22, ymax=31.5,
    xtick={1990,1991, 1992, 1993,1994,1995, 1996, 1997,1998,1999, 2000,2001, 2002,2003, 2004,2005 ,2006, 2007,2008, 2009,2010,2011, 2012,2013, 2014,2015, 2016, 2017,2018, 2019,2020, 2021,2022,2030},
    xticklabels={1990,1991, 1992,1993, 1994,1995, 1996, 1997,1998, 1999,2000, 2001,2002, 2003,2004, 2005,2006, 2007,2008, 2009,2010,2011,2012, 2013,2014, 2015,2016, 2017,2018, 2019,2020,2021,2022,2030}, 
    xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=center east},
    ytick={20, 22,23, 24,25,26,27,28,29, 30,31},
    mark options={scale=1.5},
    width=20cm,
    height=11cm,
   x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.13)},anchor=north}
]

\addplot[only marks,forget plot,scatter] coordinates {
    (1990,25)(1991,24.6)(1992,24.1)(1993,24.2)(1994,28.2)(1995,25.1)(1996,24.9)(1997,25.3)(1998,26.3)(1999,25.2)(2000,27.2)(2001,22.5)(2002,27.1)(2003,25.5)(2004,26.1)(2005,27.1)(2006,27.7)(2007,27.6)(2008,24.4)(2009,27.3)(2010,25.9)(2011,26.9)(2012,27)(2013,27.1)(2014,25)(2015,30.3)(2016,26.6)(2017,26.1)(2018,28.6)(2019,29.1)(2020,25.5)(2021,26.2)(2022,26.5)
};



\addplot[domain=1990:2030,no markers, dashed,black,line width=0.25mm] {(0.07503*(x) - 124.208)}; 



%\addlegendimage{black,dashed};
\addlegendentry{$y=0.0750334x - 124.208, R^2 = 0.2039$}


% Add node at the point (2030, 28.10989)
\node at (axis cs:2027.5,28.10989) [anchor=south, font=\scriptsize] {$P(2030,28.10989)$};

\addplot[mark=*, black] coordinates {
    (2030,28.10989)
};


\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{landscape}


\end{document}

